# PHP & HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Forgive my lack of PHP knowledge. I have followed a number of tutorials and still cannot seem to get my form to actually submit to my email.

My site is lindseyleanne.com. Does anyone have a solution as to why I get a :
"Method Not Allowed

unsupported method `POST'.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2012-09-18) at 127.0.0.1:24680"

message every time I try to submit the form.

Thank you!

Comment: Because you're using ruby and not PHP?

Comment: i visited your website...first of all, compresses your background image...it took more than a minute to load

Comment: Thank you Emilio, I compressed the image, so hopefully that problem is fixed.

Comment: Also compress the footer image. Let me just say it took a long time to load. You should at least size it down to a width of 1000px.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you're having a 500 internal server error, but here's how I would do it:

Assign names to your inputs/textareas.

```
 <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

To read this field with PHP, do the following:

```
 <?php
      $message = $_POST["message"];
 ?>
```

(For more on $_POST, see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php.)

To mail yourself, do the following:

```
 <?php
      // The message
      $message = $_POST["message"];          

      // Send
      if(mail("caffeinated@example.com", "My Subject", $message))
           echo "Thanks! I'll reply as soon as I can.";          
      else
           echo "Whoops. Couldn't send that.";
 ?>
```

(For more on mail, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.)